# Postgresql, vacuum issues

Tags: postgresql, vacuum

I experiencing issues while vacuuming a DB table:

```
database=# vacuum (verbose) table_name;
INFO:  vacuuming "public.table_name"
ERROR:  uncommitted xmin 415285800 from before xid cutoff 462314292 
needs to be frozen
```

Can someone explain what does this error mean?

Is there any solution for this problem avoiding a vacuum using "zero_damaged_pages" and "ignore_system_index" settings?

Thank you for any replies.

Comment: Did you import `table_name` from other database server ?

Comment: @LuanHuynh I try to recover database cluster from restored files after hdd crush

Comment: How was the backup taken?

Comment: @jjanes it was restored by disk recovery tools. Actually, i have removed this rows and now database works correctly

Comment: I had the same issue, but caused by pg_upgrade from Postgres 9 to Postgres 11.4. The issue occurred running vacuum in the upgraded 11 database.

Comment: @ValeriyGaydar how did you solve the issue I'm facing same problem.

Comment: @AsnadAtta, I have removed those rows.